# Java - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, exception, noclassdeffounderror

I need to compile an external java file (say a.java). This is the code i wrote for the same.

(String path contains the path to the java and class file)

```
    command[0] = "javac";
    command[1] = path+"a.java";
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

The above code seems to work just fine. But the below code

```
    command[0] = "java";
    command[1] = "a";
    command[2] = "-cp";
    command[3] = "."+path+"a";
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);        
    stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
    while ((temp = stdInput.readLine()) != null) result += "\n" + temp;
    while ((temp = stdError.readLine()) != null) result += "\n" + temp;
```

Causes the following error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: a
Exception in thread "main"
```

Could someone explaine the problem with this code. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're specifying the class name *first*, and then the arguments for the classpath. The class name is always the *last* thing to come before the program-specific arguments. In your case, the classpath part will therefore *not* be treated as an option - it'll be considered as two arguments (`-cp` and the path) to the Java program itself.

So instead of:

```
java a -cp (whatever)
```

you want

```
java -cp (whatever) a
```

Comment: I tried - 

`command[0] = "java";`
`command[1] = "-cp";`
`command[2] = "."+path+"\\temp\\";`
`command[3] = "a";`

But i'm still getting the same error. Is this command correct ?

Comment: @randomuser: Try running it from the command line first - it'll be a lot easier to experiment that way. Is the class file *in* the `temp` directory?

Comment: I get the same error when i run it using cmd, 

I found someone with same [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587585/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

It seems a similar command worked for him.

Comment: @randomuser: That problem was due to putting the class *filename* rather than the class *name*. That's not your problem - I suspect your problem is that you're not compiling into the `temp` directory.

Comment: When working with cmd, when i change the current directory to the directory containing the .java file and the .class file,
`java a` works just fine though. But when i explicitly try to avoid changing the current directory and try something like this
`java c:\\path_to_dir\\a`
I get the same error mentioned earlier.

Comment: @randomuser: But that's not the command-line you were using. You're trying `java -cp c:\\path_to_dir a` which isn't the same at all.